# Datepicker start by default with next available month

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I have a calendar that allows booking and selecting dates, but I need to disable specific weekdays, specific months, in some cases third friday or second tuesday. So I have this functions and variables. But now I realized that the calendar always start with the actual month.

In the cases that the actual month is disabled, the calendar starts with it. In this special case the actual month is august, but on the top of the calendar the select a month(dropdown) option displays the name of the next available month (as i added a code to make it remove the non-available months from the dropdown.

Please take a look to this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/amatoro/yFtLP/10/

It shows the august calendar (starting with Thursday 1st, and ending with saturday 31), but on the top it appears "sep" - September.

I need it to start with the next available month calendar. In this case September. But I cannot make it static with "defaultDate: (function to start with september)". As the days and months change, so if we were on december the calendar will be wrong if it starts with september ( i know this is something really silly to clarify, but just in case).

```
jQuery("#datepicker").datepicker({
    showOn: "button",
    dateFormat : 'yy/mm/dd',
    buttonText: "Select",
    beforeShowDay: disableSpecificWeekDaysandMonths,
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    minDate: 0,
    stepMonths: 0,
    maxDate: '2y'
}).focus(function() {
    $(".ui-datepicker-prev, .ui-datepicker-next").remove();
    $.each(
        monthsToDisable,
        function( intIndex, objValue ){     
            $(".ui-datepicker-month > option[value='" + objValue + "']").remove();
        }
     );
});

var daysToDisable = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6]; 
var monthsToDisable = [4,5,6,7]; 
var specificDaysToDisable = [5]; 
var weektoEnable = [3];

function disableSpecificWeekDaysandMonths(date) {

    var day = date.getDay();
    if ($.inArray(day, daysToDisable) != -1) {
        return [false];
    }

    var month = date.getMonth();
    if ($.inArray(month, monthsToDisable) != -1) {
        return [false];
    }

    var date2 = date.getDate();
    if ($.inArray(day, specificDaysToEnable) != -1 && date.getWeekOfMonth()!= weektoEnable) {
        return [false];
    }
    return [true]
}

Date.prototype.getWeekOfMonth = function(exact) {
    var month = this.getMonth()
        , year = this.getFullYear()
        , firstWeekday = new Date(year, month, 1).getDay()
        , lastDateOfMonth = new Date(year, month + 1, 0).getDate()
        , offsetDate = this.getDate() + firstWeekday - 1
        , index = 1 // start index at 0 or 1, your choice
        , weeksInMonth = index + Math.ceil((lastDateOfMonth + firstWeekday - 7) / 7)
        , week = index + Math.floor(offsetDate / 7)
    ;
    if (exact || week < 2 + index) return week;
    return week === weeksInMonth ? index + (weeksInMonth -1 ) : week;
};
```

I'll keep trying some options but sometimes I create really long codes that work instead of the simple and direct ones, due to my lack of knowledge.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This part allows me to disable months: `var month = date.getMonth();
    if ($.inArray(month, monthsToDisable) != -1) {
        return [false];
    }`

and with this one i select the ones to deactivate `var monthsToDisable = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]; `
O
r do you mean, the part that allows me to disable the non-available months from the dropdown?

Comment: Why aren't you using [minDate property](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-minDate)?

Comment: Because as I explained, I need to disable specific months, not only the past ones, in this example it is: [feb, mar, apr, may, jun, jul, aug]. But it could be just:  [jun, jul, aug] and it still will have the error: it stars with the actual month, but displays september on the top.

Comment: Already updated the fiddle, with a small change, and changed the months too. http://jsfiddle.net/amatoro/yFtLP/10/

Comment: You need to go to your wanted month. I can't find this kind of function or property in the API.

Comment: The thing is, for example, in september i have one available date, but when the calendar opens, i see august calendar, with september title. So if I go foward and select a different month and then i get back it shows me september in the correct way.

So the main issue will be in this case, that it's starting with current month, so i'll need to create a function to make it detect the available months, and make it start with the next available one. I'm still looking, but let's wait some other expert coders answers. Thank you so much! :)

Comment: I understood what the problem was. I was just saying I got stuck

Comment: Yeah sorry, it's that i forgot that hitting "enter" the comment is sent, so i was editing it to have it complete. Also wanted to clarify as my english is not as quite as good as native speakers, so i was trying to explain it better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do it but still have some small things to cover. Here is basically ready but I still need to find a way to make the "9 (next available month)" at defaultAvailableDate function dynamic and not static. I mean, create a function to complement defaultAvailableDate to make it calculate the next available month. Perhaps someone will be able to help guide me:

Fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/amatoro/9tSJh/6/

The code below works as expected, but as the "next month" is static I won't be able to use it for all the trips:

```
 Date.prototype.getWeekOfMonth = function(exact) {
     var month = this.getMonth()
         , year = this.getFullYear()
         , firstWeekday = new Date(year, month, 1).getDay()
         , lastDateOfMonth = new Date(year, month + 1, 0).getDate()
         , offsetDate = this.getDate() + firstWeekday - 1
         , index = 1 // start index at 0 or 1, your choice
         , weeksInMonth = index + Math.ceil((lastDateOfMonth + firstWeekday - 7) / 7)
         , week = index + Math.floor(offsetDate / 7)
     ;
     if (exact || week < 2 + index) return week;
     return week === weeksInMonth ? index + (weeksInMonth -1 ) : week;
 };

 jQuery("#datepicker").datepicker({
     showOn: "button",
     dateFormat : 'yy/mm/dd',
     buttonText: "Select",
     beforeShowDay: disableSpecificWeekDaysandMonths,
     changeMonth: true,
     changeYear: true,
     minDate: 0,
     stepMonths: 0,
     maxDate: '2y',
     defaultDate: defaultAvailableDate(),
 }).focus(function() {
     $(".ui-datepicker-prev, .ui-datepicker-next").remove();
     $.each(
         monthsToDisable,
         function( intIndex, objValue ){     
             $(".ui-datepicker-month > option[value='" + objValue + "']").remove();
         }
      );
 });

 var daysToDisable = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6]; 
 var monthsToDisable = [5,6,7,8]; 
 var specificDaysToEnable = [5]; 
 var weektoEnable = [3];


 function defaultAvailableDate( ) { 
     var d = new Date();
     var n = d.getMonth(); 
     var monthsToDisable = [5,6,7,8]; 

     if( $.inArray(n, monthsToDisable) != -1){

       var offset = (n < 9) ? 0 : null;
       var availableMonth = 9 + offset - n;
       return '+' + availableMonth+ 'm';   

     } else {
          return '';   
     }

 }

 function disableSpecificWeekDaysandMonths(date) {

     var day = date.getDay();
     if ($.inArray(day, daysToDisable) != -1) {
         return [false];
     }

     var month = date.getMonth();
     if ($.inArray(month, monthsToDisable) != -1) {
         return [false];
     }

     var date2 = date.getDate();
     var inArray = $.inArray(day, specificDaysToEnable);
     if (inArray != -1 && date.getWeekOfMonth()!= weektoEnable) {
         return [false];
     }
     return [true]
 }
```

Thanks!